# In Django, how can I deal with static content within a CSS file?

Tags: django

For example I may wish to loading images as follows:

```
background: url("/path/to/image.png")
```

However because CSS files are not run through the templating system I don't have access to the usual

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

What is the correct way to deal with such static content?

Comment: Try: `url("{{STATIC_URL}}/relative/path/to/image.png")` If not, you would can do `relative absolute paths` which is relative to the "root" of the project

Comment: Like `{% load staticfiles %}`, `{{STATIC_URL}}` will not work outside the template system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser already knows the css file path, so just use relative URLs instead:

```
background: url("../img/image.png")
```

[EDIT]

> But what happens if I have a page at /onelevel And another page at /really/deeply/nested/page won't this break the relative system? Also if I eventually choose to host the static content externally ideally I would like the study content management to be as DRY as possible - OP.

Let me explain. In order to read the CSS file, the browser has to download it first. In order to download it, the CSS file URL must be known. So the browser already knows the path to the CSS file. Lets suppose you are hosting your media at a CDN, and the URL is:

```
http://cdn.yoursite.com/css/style.css
```

When you use a relative URL like `../img/logo.png`, the browser will take the path to the CSS file (`http://cdn.yoursite.com/css/`) and append `../img/logo.png` to it.

It works well, is shorter than the whole path and let you reuse the media in other projects/applications without changing a dot. You can't get more DRY.

That is why you don't need settings.STATIC_URL anywhere near your CSS files, it will be derived from the file URL at HTTP serving time.

Comment: But what happens if I have a page at

/onelevel

And another page at

/really/deeply/nested/page

won't this break the relative system?

Also if I eventually choose to host the static content externally ideally I would like the study content management to be as DRY as possible

Comment: No because `settings.STATIC_URL` is fixed and has nothing to do with the dynamic content URLs. So static files will always be in a fixed position relative to each other. You can't go more DRY than having all your static media loosely coupled with the application.